# javascript to post form via buttons, one works one does not

Tags: javascript, forms, post, onclick

i have the following in menuSubmit.js

```
    function submitIndexList() {
        var key = document.getElementsByName("key").value;
        var page = document.getElementsByName("page").value;
        document.getElementById("listSelect").submit();
    }
    function submitIndexAbcd() {
        var key = document.getElementByName("key").value;
        var page = document.getElementsByName("page").value;
        document.getElementById("abcdSelect").submit();
    }
```

page is:

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post" name="listSelect" id="listSelect">
        <input name="page" id="<?php echo($pagekey);?>" value="<?php echo($pagekey);?>" type="hidden" />
        <input name="key" id="list" value="list" type="hidden" />
        <input class="menubutton" type="button" value="Categories" onclick="submitIndexList()" />
    </form>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" name="abcdSelect" id="abcdSelect">
        <input name="page" id="<?php echo($pagekey);?>" value="<?php echo($pagekey);?>" type="hidden" />
        <input name="key" id="az" value="az" type="hidden" /> 
        <input class="menubutton" type="button" value="A to Z" onclick="submitIndexAbcd()" />
    </form>
```

changes the index on the side to display list a-z or by category, page defaults a-z. as the page defaults a-z i click the categories button and it refreshes page and index.php sees key=list and displays the categorical list. 
now i try the a-z button to go back and we are no go.

ive tried using

```
    <input name="keyCat" id="list" ... >
    <input name="keyAbc" id="az" ... >
```

changing values in javascript as necessary, and adding something to check for either key in original index..

```
    var keyCat = document.getElementsByName("keyCat").value;
    var keyAbc = document.getElementsByName("keyAbc").value;
```

i tried doing both buttons in a single form, separate forms, same name for my key, different names.. any way i slice it only the first button works. i tried to run both buttons using the same onclick="function()" so i made the second function. nothing changes.. what am i missing?

Comment: What is the reason for your `key` and  `page` variables? You don't use them. Do you have your browser cache disabled? Otherwise, it might be still the old code which gets executed.

Comment: Your input names have the same names (key and page) in both forms. So, `document.getElementsByName("key")` will returns an array of values. 
You say you tried chaging names, but do you have changed keeping the sames values between forms or trying to put differents names depending form ?

Comment: in all honesty i dont know.. i recently got into simple web coding recently and alot of this is still foreign to me. i will say your question caused me to rethink my scenario. i dont have the variables anymore and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

changed javascript to

```
    function submitIndexList() {
        document.listSelect.submit();
    }
    function submitIndexAbcd() {
        document.abcdSelect.submit();
    }
```

maintained html/php code:

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post" name="listSelect" id="listSelect">
        <input name="page" id="<?php echo($pagekey);?>" value="<?php echo($pagekey);?>" type="hidden" />
        <input name="key" id="list" value="list" type="hidden" />
        <input class="menubutton" type="button" value="Categories" onclick="submitIndexList()" />
    </form>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" name="abcdSelect" id="abcdSelect">
        <input name="page" id="<?php echo($pagekey);?>" value="<?php echo($pagekey);?>" type="hidden" />
        <input name="key" id="az" value="az" type="hidden" /> 
        <input class="menubutton" type="button" value="A to Z" onclick="submitIndexAbcd()" />
    </form>
```

sorry for the trouble, im a noob.. i should have used more resources before wasting everyones time.
functions as i had hoped for.

Comment: props to you for fixing it yourself